# Paypal app. From sandbox to live

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I implemented paypal sandbox in my application and after hours of headaches with their documentation, I managed to implement a working app that uses their RestAPI. Now I want to go live with the application.

In their documentation the steps to go live with the app are as follows:

```
1. Ensure your application adheres to the PayPal Application Policies and Guidelines.
2. Update the Sandbox API credentials in your PayPal calls to those assigned to a live PayPal account.
3. Update your PayPal endpoints from the Sandbox to the PayPal production servers.
4. Register your application with PayPal.
5. If your application makes use of Adaptive operations, obtain a live AppID.
6. Go Live!
```

I don't understand how can I register my application with PayPal (point 4). In the documentation, it says that my app needs to be approved by PayPal and that's it. How do I do that ? How do I submit my app for reviewing ?

If I understand correctly, point 1, 2 and 3 affect only my code, registering the new credentials, right ?

Finally, I need an appID, but I guess that comes as soon as the app has been approved by PayPal to go live.

The full documentation I followed is [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Per [Paypal Documentation : Registering your application with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register) :

> Submitting your application
>
> To submit your website or mobile application to PayPal:
>
> Log into the PayPal Developer website using the credentials of the
>   PayPal account registered to the application owner.
>
> Note: The PayPal account associated with the application must be a
>   verified Premier or verified Business account. Click Dashboard at the
>   top of the page to open the My Apps & Credentials page. (Alternately,
>   you can go directly to the My Applications page by navigating to the
>   My Apps & Credentials page on the Developer website.)
>
> Registering a REST API app
>
> In the REST API apps section, click Create app. See creating an app
>   for more information. Registering an NVP/SOAP API app
>
> Click Dashboard at the top of the page to open the My Apps &
>   Credentials page. Click the Create and manage NVP/SOAP API apps link
>   at the bottom of the page. Click New App on the left nav bar to access
>   the App Information form. Complete the form and click the Submit App
>   button. To ensure the fastest possible application review, supply as
>   much information as possible when completing the submittal form. Tip:
>   When filling out the application, be sure to provide the e-mail
>   address that corresponds to the PayPal account that is used make API
>   calls. The type of API operations used in your application dictates
>   the review process applied to your application. PayPal divides
>   applications into three distinct review categories:
>
> Merchant APIs include Express Checkout, Website Payments Pro, Button
>   Manager, Mass Pay, Recurring Payments, and all of the Informational
>   APIs. Adaptive APIs include Adaptive Payments, Adaptive Accounts, the
>   Permissions Service, and the Invoicing Service. Calls to these APIs
>   require an AppID value. Mass Pay includes only the MassPay operation

Answer (score 1):

As per 2020
PayPal developer guideline, you just have to mail them all the required things that they want to register your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to http://developer.paypal.com.
2. Click on the Dashboard menu item at the top.
3. Under the REST API Apps section, click the Create App button.
4. Proceed with the steps to create the app.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have created the app long ago, but it is under sandbox release. I want to go live with it. How do I go live with this app ?